# writeOGR alters MultiPolygon holes

Tags: gdal, geojson, rgdal

I'having trouble using `writeOGR` to write GeoJSON files, when there are MultiPolygon objects. Here is an example: I'm creating a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` object from GeoJSON, with a single feature made of two polygons. When I export to GeoJSON, the file that's written has a single feature with one polygon and a hole.

Why is this, and how can I persuade writeOGR to write two polygons?

```
# Create SpatialPolygonsDataFrame with one feature, two polygons
spdf <- readOGR(layer='OGRGeoJSON', verbose=FALSE, '{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [{
 "type": "Feature",
 "id": 0,
 "properties": {"label":"CENTRAL"},
 "geometry": {
     "type": "MultiPolygon",
     "coordinates": [[[[102.0, 2.0], [103.0, 2.0], [103.0, 3.0], [102.0, 3.0], [102.0, 2.0]]],
                     [[[100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0]]]]
     } }] }')

# When I save and reload this object, coordinates has length 1,
# i.e. the feature is a polygon and a hole.
fn <- tempfile()
writeOGR(spdf, fn, layer='whatever', driver='GeoJSON')
length(fromJSON(file=fn)$features[[1]]$geometry$coordinates)
```

I'm using R 3.1.2 and rgdal 0.9.1 on OSX Yosemite.

UPDATE: Here is the GeoJSON tempfile that is created. As you can see, the coordinates array has been modified from the original.

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
    { "type": "Feature",
      "id": 0,
      "properties": { "label": "CENTRAL" },
      "geometry": {
          "type": "MultiPolygon",
          "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 102.0, 2.0 ], [ 102.0, 3.0 ], [ 103.0, 3.0 ], [ 103.0, 2.0 ], [ 102.0, 2.0 ] ],
                             [ [ 100.0, 0.0 ], [ 100.0, 1.0 ], [ 101.0, 1.0 ], [ 101.0, 0.0 ], [ 100.0, 0.0 ] ] ] ] } }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is the result that you wait from the length test? Could you convert the source feature and the saved feature into WKT? That way it would be easier to read what has changed.

Comment: The input GeoJSON has length(coordinates)=2, signifying "union of two disjoint polygons", so I expect the output to have length(coordinates)=2. Instead it has length(coordinates)=1, signifying "polygon with hole".

Comment: There's definitely a problem with conversion somewhere (either readOGR/writeOGR, or my own understanding). Therefore I won't attempt to convert the features into WKT, for fear of muddling the issue further.

Comment: Could you paste then the contents of the tempfile? I made a simple test by converting your source GeoJSON into another GeoJSON file with ogr2ogr and your multipolygon stayed as an identical multipolygon.

Comment: Update: I added the tempfile output to my question.

Comment: I am clueless. Perhaps there is something strange in rgdal 0.9.1.

Comment: I'm running into similar issues. Did you find an answer DamonJW?

Comment: @andyteucher I didn't find the answer, so I wrote my own toGeoJSON() function. I've posted the most useful code snippet below.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way to get `writeOGR` to work -- so instead, I wrote my own `toGeoJSON` function. I won't paste the full code, but the bit that's most useful is the following, for an object `x` of class `'Polygons'`:

```
require(maptools)
require(rgeos)
y <- maptools::checkPolygonsHoles(x)
insideWhich <- as.numeric(strsplit(rgeos::createPolygonsComment(y),' ')[[1]])
plotOrder <- y@plotOrder
```

For example, you might get

```
plotOrder = c(3,5,4,1,2)
insideWhich = c(4,3,0,0,0)
```

This means: "Plot polygon 4, then 5, then 1, then 3, then 2.
Also, polygon 1 is a hole inside 4, and 2 is a hole inside 3."
The two functions `checkPolygonsHoles` and `createPolygonsComment`
work together to compute these facts. With this information, the
rest of creating a GeoJSON object is fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow up on this thread:

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2015-October/023609.html

as rgdal developers do not read SO, the bug affects multiple drivers, so the whole point of using GDAL as a single interface to all data formats is defeated by spreading effort.

The issue is in how wkbtype MultiPolygon objects are written through the OGR class system - rgdal (OGR_write.cpp for this wkbtype) may not be doing it in a way that suits all drivers, and seems to fail on SFS-compliant ones.